# sql query joining three tables in sequence

Tags: asp.net, sql, join

I am having problems joining three tables. I need *all from AUser, CountryName from ACountry & StateName from AState*. This is the query I tried. The result I am getting gives one row for each state. It should return only 1 row for each user since a user can have only one state in his/her address.

```
SELECT * 
FROM AUser join ACountry on AUser.Country_ID=ACountry.ID 
     join AState on ACountry.ID=AState.Country_ID 
where AUser.Email='abc@gmail.com'
```

[image: tables]

Comment: what is the relationship between the tables?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that you need a state_id column on AUser.
Or more likely on AUserAddress, so join to user address using AUser.id, and then join to AState using a state id from AUserAddress.

Try query below ... and next time don't be lazy - show your own attempt first !

```
SELECT u.*
FROM AUser u
join ACountry c
  on c.ID = u.Country_ID
join AUserAddress a
  on a.user_ID = u.ID
join AState s
  on s.ID = a.State_ID
where AUser.Email='abc@gmail.com'
```

Comment: I do have a state_ID in AUserAddress... So what would be the query then?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM AUser 
left join ACountry on AUser.Country_ID=ACountry.ID 
left join AState on ACountry.ID=AState.Country_ID 
where AUser.Email='abc@gmail.com "'
```

Comment: @Aditya Nawandar just comment the where clause and see if you are getting any data.

Answer (score 0):

In AUser table you don't have information about user's state, for example column named State_ID, only information about Country is present. So you can't filter user's state.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
 (SELECT * FROM AUser join AUserAddress on AUserAddress.AUser_ID=AUser.ID join ACountry on AUserAddress.Country_ID=ACountry.ID join AState on AUserAddress.State_ID=AState.ID where AUser.Email='abc@gmail.com')"
```

Thanks @ Crowne.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select AUser.*,ACountry.CountryName,AState.StateName from AUser 
left join ACountry on AUser.Country_ID=ACountry.ID 
left join AState on ACountry.ID=AState.Country_ID 
where AUser.Email='abc@gmail.com'
```